Due to insufficient memory, it was not possible to complete the previous operation problem
Let's go, I have a site that creates a link for the user, the user opens this link on the cell phone (because I created methods so that the page only opens in mobile mode) on the cell phone he needs to open the camera to take a picture of his vehicle, but when I open the camera and take a picture I come across this error (information) 'Due to insufficient memory, it was not possible to complete the previous operation problem' this error (information) is in all browsers I have already tried to compress my code to base64 and I have already used packages such as image compressor (however as I use AI to check the photo I cannot use these compressors because of the quality of the image).
Is there any alternative to escape this error (information)?
My code for reading the image and transforming it into base64:
async readURL(input: any) {
  if (input.target.files && input.target.files[0]) {
    const file = input.target.files[0];
    const timeStampNow = Date.now();

    if (this.laudo?.validacaoCamera) {
      if (file.lastModified < timeStampNow - 5000) {
        this.bloquearBotaoDeCamera = true;
        return;
      }
    }

    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      try {
        reader.onload = async (e: any) => {
          const buffer = e.target.result as ArrayBuffer;
          const Data = ExifParserFactory.create(buffer).parse();

          if (Data.tags?.GPSLatitude === undefined || Data.tags?.GPSLongitude === undefined) {
            this.geolocalizacaoService.geolocalizacao$.subscribe((geolocation) => {
              this.geolocalizacaoDaFoto = geolocation;
            });
          } else {
            const geolocation: IGeolocalizacao | null = {
              latitude: Data.tags?.GPSLatitude,
              longitude: Data.tags?.GPSLongitude,
            };

            this.geolocalizacaoDaFoto = geolocation;
          }

          this.geolocalizacaoCapturada.emit(this.geolocalizacaoDaFoto);
          this.fotoArquivo = file;

          this.fotoArquivoBase64 = await this.getBase64(file);

          this.fotoCapturada.emit(this.fotoArquivoBase64);
          this.arquivoFoto.emit(this.fotoArquivo!);

          if (!this.geolocalizacaoDaFoto) {
            this.snackbarService.mostrarErro("Não foi possível capturar a geolocalização");
            return;
          }

          if (!this.fotoArquivo) {
            this.snackbarService.mostrarErro("Não foi possível capturar a foto");
            return;
          }

          const foto: IFoto = {
            geolocalizacao: this.geolocalizacaoDaFoto,
            arquivo: this.fotoArquivo,
          };

          this.onCapturaFoto.emit(foto);
          this.chRef.detectChanges();
        };
      } catch (error) {
        // Tratar erro
      }
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
  }
}

async getBase64(file: File) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve({ foto: reader.result });
    reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
  }).then((result: any) => {
    return result.foto;
  });
}




  async readURL(input: any) {  
    if (input.target.files && input.target.files[0]) {
      const file = input.target.files[0];
      const timeStampNow = Date.now();    
      
      if (this.laudo?.validacaoCamera && file.lastModified < timeStampNow - 5000 ) {   
        this.bloquearBotaoDeCamera = true;
        return;        
      }      
      
      const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
      const data = ExifParserFactory.create(buffer).parse();

      if (data.tags?.GPSLatitude === undefined || data.tags?.GPSLongitude === undefined) {
        this.geolocalizacaoService.geolocalizacao$.subscribe((geolocation) => {
          this.geolocalizacaoDaFoto = geolocation;
        });
      } else {
        this.geolocalizacaoDaFoto = {
          latitude: data.tags?.GPSLatitude,
          longitude: data.tags?.GPSLongitude,
        };
      }

      this.geolocalizacaoCapturada.emit(this.geolocalizacaoDaFoto);  
      const fotoURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);      

      this.fotoArquivoURL = fotoURL;
      this.fotoArquivo = file;

      if (this.fotoArquivo) {
        this.arquivoFoto.emit(this.fotoArquivo); 
      }

      this.fotoCapturada.emit(fotoURL);

      setTimeout(() => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(fotoURL);
      }, 0);     

     
      if (!this.geolocalizacaoDaFoto) {
        this.snackbarService.mostrarErro('Não foi possível capturar a geolocalização');
        return;
      }

      if (!this.fotoArquivo) {
        this.snackbarService.mostrarErro('Não foi possível capturar a foto');
        return;
      }

      const foto: IFoto = {
        geolocalizacao: this.geolocalizacaoDaFoto,
        arquivo: this.fotoArquivo,
      };

      this.onCapturaFoto.emit(foto);
      this.chRef.detectChanges();
    }
  }  


Your getBase64 function has numerous problems... first-off, you do not need to read the file from within JS and use
data: URIs or Base64/Base64Url encoding: it's much, much, much faster and lighter to use createObjectURL and pass that around.

Also, don't mix async/await with manually creating Promises: use one style or the other. Right now your getBase64 function will return Promise<Promise<string|ArrayBufer>> - which also might explain the memory issues because it means it's incorrectly restarting the promise internally instead of reusing the last result.

Thanks for answering my question, I used your tips, but I still get the same error in the browser....
Is there anything I can do to clear everything from the browser first or can I get the 'insufficient memory' error from the browser through my js code? my code literally opens a web page so I can take a picture and read that picture to perform some operations...
I've added the function that does this to the content of this post
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

Your browser's devtools window has a memory-profiler which will tell you how memory is being used: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/memory
